# Moving drupal to a subdirectory

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to move a Drupal site to a sub-directory of the same domain. I'm very experienced with WordPress but not experienced with Drupal sites. How would I move a website from http://example.com to http://example.com/old-website/ ?

I can't figure out what would cahnge so that I can migrate the site.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Austin

Answer (score 1):

Just move the files, you don't need to set a base URL like in Wordpress.

If you do run into any problems, uncomment rewritebase in htaccess

Comment: The website now live at example.com/old-website/

Is there a simple way to use rewrite rules to make image links pointing here: https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/picture.png

to point to here: https://www.example.com/old-website/sites/default/files/picture.png

Comment: You should have always used relative urls instead of absolute urls which would make transferring the site really easy. I would use find and replace in your database to change the paths.