# How do I move files and directories after installation?

Tags: 8

I moved directory within a server so the Drupal 8 installed URL should change from *ip-address/old-folder/d8* to *my-site.com/d8/*.

When I checked the new URL, the front page worked, but other pages gave a 404 error that said *old-folder/d8/admin/structure/*.

I read [Moving drupal to a subdirectory](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163322/moving-drupal-to-a-subdirectory), but the answer there didn't resolve my problem.

Which file/config I should change in Drupal 8.6?

Comment: Probably RewriteBase in .htaccess needs to change.

Comment: There is no config option, Drupal 8 can run from any directory without configuration change. You only need to clear the cache.

Comment: How about DB changes? Do I need to make changes in base url value? Because it's still showing 404 error after clearing cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you just need to clear (or 'rebuild' as it is often called nowadays) the cache, as 4k4 is suggesting in a comment.

There are several ways you can do that:

1. The "built-in" option is to go to /admin/config/development/performance and hit the clear cache button there.
2. Another popular option is with drush, where you could issue `drush cr` to rebuild the cache from the command line. Your site or server would need to have drush installed, though. It can be a lifesaver if for whatever reason you can't get to the UI page, though.
3. In a similar vain, drupal console (a tool quite similar to drush) can do the same thing, with `drupal cache:rebuild`, `drupal cr` or `drupal cc`.
4. If you are running with the default database cache mechanism, you can truncate the tables that start with `cache_` as their table name. Treat this as a last resort, though, and do make a backup in case you make a mistake. In particular, do *not* truncate the cachetags table.